# Daemon in C# to listen for keypress

Tags: c#, keyboard, daemon, keypress

I'm looking to create a small C# application that will either run as a daemon or sit in the taskbar, and wait for a specific keypress.  When the expected keypress is encountered, I'll perform some actions.

This is going to be used primarily for quick-posting of data to a web-service I'm writing.  I've looked around the net for a while, but my search terms have been too vague, and I haven't come across any concrete examples or guides.

Thanks,

Mike Trpcic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this on CodeProject. It'll capture keystrokes while it's not focused.
[CodeProject: A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx?fid=423705&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2800876)

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like it can do exactly what I need.  Any idea if this is capable of binding key combinations (e.g. CTRL+Space)?

Comment: The KeyEventArgs contains boolean properties to check if shift, alt, and control are pressed. So yes, I believe it would be pretty simple to implement key combinations.

Comment: I'm running into the same task, but it seems like they hook is working everywhere except on Excel. Is this working fro you Mike?